# Lookaround lookbefore regex for R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to use regular expressions using the stringr package to extract some text.  For some reason, I'm getting and 'Invalid regexp' error.  I have tried the regex expression in some website test tools, and it seems to work there.  I was wondering if there is something unique about how regex works in R and particularly in the stringr package.

Here is an example:

```
string <- c("MARKETING:  Vice President", "FINANCE:  Accountant I",
"OPERATIONS: Plant Manager")

pattern <- "[A-Z]+(?=:)"
test <- gsub(" ","",string)
results <- str_extract(test, pattern)
```

This doesn't seems to be working.  I would like to get "MARKETING", "FINANCE", and "OPERATIONS" without the ":" in them.  That is why I"m using the lookahead syntax.  I realize that I can just work around this using:

```
pattern <- "[A-Z]+(:)"
test <- gsub(" ","",string)
results <- gsub(":","",str_extract(test, pattern))
```

But I anticipate that I might need to use lookarounds for more complex situations than this in the near future.

Do I need to amend the regex with some escapes or something to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lookahead assertions require you to identify the regular expression as a perl regular expression in R.

```
str_extract(string, perl(pattern))
# [1] "MARKETING"  "FINANCE"    "OPERATIONS"
```

You can also do this easily in base R:

```
regmatches(string, regexpr(pattern, string, perl=TRUE))
# [1] "MARKETING"  "FINANCE"    "OPERATIONS"
```

`regexpr` finds the matches and `regmatches` use the match data to extract the substrings.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly with `sub` and grouping.

```
sub('^([A-Z]+):.*$', '\\1', string)

# [1] "MARKETING"  "FINANCE"    "OPERATIONS"
```

Where I am fixing the group to the start of a line, looking for one or more capital letters and saving them.  They must be followed by a colon, `:` and then zero or more additional characters.